# Find Quadratic Bezier curve equation based on its control points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics, bezier-curve

If the 3 control points of the quadratic Bézier curve are known, how do you calculate algebraically the equation of that curve (which is an y=f(x) function)?
Let's say I have..

- P0 (x,y) - startPoint
- P1 (x,y) - controlPoint
- P2 (x,y) - endPoint

and I want to get implicit equation for that, something like that:

f(x) = −0.5x^2​​ + 3.5x − 1 (for example).

I've found the [fang's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/180792/fang) solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257576/convert-quadratic-bezier-curve-to-parabola), but he says

> Although all quadric Bezier curve is part of a certain parabola, not all parabola can be represented as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. So, the first thing you need to do is check if $x_2=\frac{x_1+x_3}{2}$. If this check fails, then your quadratic Bezier curve is not a segment of $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

Ok, but if check fails how can I find its equation?

Another article about cubic Bezier is http://www.moshplant.com/direct-or/bezier/math.html Is there any approach for quadratic?

Answer (score 10):

The equation of the curve is 
$$
\mathbf{C}(t) = (1-t)^2 \mathbf{P}_0 + 2t(1-t)\mathbf{P}_1 + t^2\mathbf{P}_2
$$
If we let $\mathbf{P}_0 = (x_0,y_0)$, $\mathbf{P}_1 = (x_1,y_1)$, $\mathbf{P}_2 = (x_2,y_2)$, then we can write two separate equations for $x$ and $y$:
$$
x(t) = (1-t)^2 x_0 + 2t(1-t)x_1 + t^2 x_2 
$$
$$
y(t) = (1-t)^2 y_0 + 2t(1-t)y_1 + t^2 y_2 
$$

You can rearrange and collect powers of $t$, if you want to:
$$
x(t) = (x_0 - 2x_1 + x_2)t^2 + 2(x_1 - x_0)t + x_0
$$
$$
y(t) = (y_0 - 2y_1 + y_2)t^2 + 2(y_1 - y_0)t + y_0
$$
As you mentioned, it is not always possible to write the curve in the form $y=f(x)$. For example, the curve
$$
x(t) = (t - \tfrac12)^2 \quad ; \quad y(t) = t - \tfrac12
$$
has equation $x = y^2$. We could write $y = \sqrt x$, but this is only half of the curve (the other half is $y = -\sqrt x$).

However, you can always write a quadratic Bezier curve in the form $g(x,y)=0$, where $g$ is some second-degree function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much, bubba! It's what I need! Very useful!

Comment: Is it possible to clearly jump from this general form x(t)=(x0−2x1+x2)t2+(2x1−2x2)t+x0, y(t)=(y0−2y1+y2)t2+(2y1−2y2)t+y0 to g(x,y)=0 form? (I mean in general case, if we don't know any coefficients.)

Comment: Yes, that process is called "implicitization", and it's pretty easy for quadratic and cubic curves. You'll find answers giving you the details if you search this site or elsewhere.

Comment: Like this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530310/parabola-in-parametric-form/530547?s=7|0.1119#530547

Comment: Thank you very much, bubba! But that process isn't so easy for me ;) Now I trying to understand [these notes by Tom Sederberg](http://cagd.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch17.pdf) Is it really so easy for quadratic curves?

Comment: This should be marked as an answer.