# Convert 2nd degree rational Bézier to parametric ellipse or hyperbola

Tags: algebraic-geometry, bezier-curve

I want to convert a 2nd degree rational Bézier curve in 3 dimensions (4 if in homogeneous coordinates) into a conic parametric curve.

Given a rational bezier curve of degree 2: $$B(t) = \frac{(1-t)^2 P_0 w_0 + 2 t (1 - t) P_1 w_1 + t^2 P_2 w_2}{(1-t)^2 w_0 + 2 t (1 - t) w_1 + t^2 w_2}, P_i \in \mathbb{R}^3, w_i \in \mathbb{R} $$

I want to convert this to an equal curve of the form

$E(s) = C_E + f_1 cos(s) + f_2 sin(s)$ if it is an ellipse, or

$H(s) = C_H + f_1 cosh(s) + f_2 sinh(s) $ if it is a hyperbola

Alternative form: $B(t) = \frac{t^2A+tB+C}{t^2w_A+tw_B+w_C}$, with

$A = P_0 w_0 - 2 P_1 w_1 + P_2 w_2$

$B = 2 P_1 w_1 - 2 P_0 w_0$

$C = P_0 w_0$

---

I have a partial solution for the ellipse case:

I'm not exactly sure why, but it seems that at the point $t_0$ where the weight term $t^2w_A+tw_B+w_C$ has its extrema ($2 t_0 w_A + w_B = 0 \Rightarrow t_0 = -w_B / 2 / w_A$), the segment from $B(t_0)$ to $B(\infty) = A / w_A$ crosses the center of the ellipse. Hence we get the center of the ellipse:

$C_E = \frac{1}{2}(B(t_0) + B(\infty))$

for $f_1$ we can choose the vector from the center to $B(\infty)$

$f_1 = \frac{1}{2}(B(\infty) - B(t_0)) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{A}{w_A} - \frac{C}{w_C})$

To get $f_2$ we can use the fact that $E(\pi/2) = C_E + f_2$ and $E'(\pi/2) = f_1$. (I.e. the point at which the tangent of the ellipse is parallel to $f_1$ is equal to $C_E + f_2$). As B and E have different parameters, the derivates are different, however the derivates in the same point are parallel. I.e. we need to figure out for which $t_1$ $B'(t_1) = u f_1, u \in \mathbb{R}$ (For simplification I am assuming that $t_0 = 0$ in the following equations. If it is not, an equal Bézier with $t_0$ shifted to $0$ can be obtained by expanding $B(t + t_0)$)

$$B'(t) = \frac{t^2 (A w_B - B w_A) + 2t(A w_C-Cw_A)+(Bw_C-Cw_B)}{(t^2 w_A + t w_B + w_C)^2} = u f_1$$

As the denominator is a simple scalar, it does not change the direction of the vector and can be ignored in this case. The 1/2 scalar in $f_1$'s definition can also be ignored:

$$t^2 (A w_B - B w_A) + 2t(A w_C-Cw_A)+(Bw_C-Cw_B) = u (Aw_C - Cw_A)$$

Subtracting $2t(A w_C-Cw_A)$ from both sides does not change the direction either:

$$t^2 (A w_B - B w_A) +(Bw_C-Cw_B) = u (Aw_C - Cw_A))$$

The above equation is satisfied with $t_1 = \sqrt{w_C /w_A}$ and we can calculate:

$f_2 = B(t_1) - C_E$

I have two issues with the above solution: a) it breaks down when the weights are chosen such that $w_A = 0$, as $t_0$ is undefined. b) While the steps for the center and $f_1$ work analogously in the case of a hyperbola, I have not been able to figure out a similar condition to calculate $f_2$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1258406/230980) for a similar question suggests converting the rational bezier into a matrix conic form, however I'm not sure this works in 3D?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but [here's](https://naridal.github.io/brep.ts/BREP.ts) a rendering; B(t) in cyan, $P_0 = (1, 0), P_1 = (1, 1), P2=(0, 1), w_0 = 1.1, w_1 = sqrt(2) / 3, w_2 = 1$, in green is the same curve in homogeneous coords, the blue arrow denotes the w axis. [legend](https://naridal.github.io/brep.ts/BREP.ts_files/ellipsecenter.PNG) drag-RMB: rotate/ drag-MMB: pan/ wheel: zoom

Comment: You can work in the plane defined by the three control points and then lift that solution back to 3-D.

Comment: Your “alternative form” for $B(t)$ doesn’t look right. If you expand the original expression and collect terms, the coefficient of $t^2$ in the numerator is $w_0P_0-2w_1P_1+w_2P_2$, which is in general not equal to some constant times $P_0-2P_1+P2$.

Comment: You can’t have $w_A=w_0-2w_1+w_2=0$ for an ellipse, otherwise it would include a point at infinity.

Comment: @amd You're right, of course, I messed up while writing the question; I've edited it. The calculation for $f_2$ is still correct. I ended up figuring out a similar condition for the hyperbola: B'(x -> 0) describes the direction of the asymptote, which need to be parallel to $f_1 + f_2$. Not that it matters, as your solution is much simpler!

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard Have you ever resolved the correct representation of the ellipse in terms of the parameters listed here, that is, $C_E$, $f_1$, and $f_2$? If so, please let me know as I would like to use this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have made things a bit harder for yourself by trying to work directly with the control points in 3D. Since affine transformations don’t change the type of a conic, I suggest working with a simple case in the plane and then mapping it to the control points that you have. Furthermore, I would work in homogeneous coordinates to avoid having to treat various infinities as special cases. In homogeneous coordinates, the quadratic rational Bézier parameterization becomes the simpler to work with $$R(t) = (1-t)^2w_0\mathbf p_0+2t(1-t)w_1\mathbf p_1+t^2w_2\mathbf p_2.\tag1$$ This can be viewed as the image of the parabola described by the quadratic Bézier $B$ with the same control points under the homography with matrix $$\mathtt H = \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf p_0&\mathbf p_1&\mathbf p_2\end{bmatrix} \operatorname{diag}(w_0,w_1,w_2) \, \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf p_0&\mathbf p_1&\mathbf p_2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$ This homography maps the control points to themselves and the parabola’s “infinity point” $[t^2]B(t) = \mathbf p_0-2\mathbf p_1+\mathbf p_2$ to the “infinity point” $\mathbf p_\infty = [t^2]R(t) = w_0\mathbf p_0-2w_1\mathbf p_1+w_2\mathbf p_2$. I won’t be making use of this here, but it provides an alternate route to derive what follows.

We can write an implicit Cartesian equation for $R(t)$ directly by making use of Plücker’s mu: Let $\mathbf l_{ij}=\mathbf p_i\times\mathbf p_j$ be the line through control points $\mathbf p_i$ and $\mathbf p_j$. Then an equation of the conic described by $R$ is $$(\mathbf l_{02}\cdot\mathbf x)^2(\mathbf l_{01}\cdot\mathbf p_\infty)(\mathbf l_{12}\cdot\mathbf p_\infty) = (\mathbf l_{02}\cdot\mathbf p_\infty)^2(\mathbf l_{01}\cdot\mathbf x)(\mathbf l_{12}\cdot\mathbf x). \tag2$$ The equation $(\mathbf l_{01}\cdot\mathbf x)(\mathbf l_{12}\cdot\mathbf x) = 0$ represents the degenerate conic consisting of the two tangent lines while $(\mathbf l_{02}\cdot\mathbf x)^2=0$ is the double line through the outer control points. Equation (2) is a linear combination of these two conics that passes through $\mathbf p_\infty$ (which, somewhat ironically, is the only point of this conic that is *not* generated by $R$).

Taking the simple case of $\mathbf p_0=[1:0:1]$, $\mathbf p_1=[0:0:1]$ and $\mathbf p_2=[0:1:1]$, we have $\mathbf p_\infty = [w_0:w_2:w_0-2w_1+w_2]$ and equation (2) expands to $$w_0w_2(x+y-1)^2 = 4w_1^2xy.\tag3$$ This is an ellipse when $\Delta = w_0w_2 - w_1^2 \gt 0$, a parabola when $\Delta=0$ and a hyperbola when $\Delta\lt0$. The center of this conic can be found to be $\mathbf c = [w_0w_2:w_0w_2:2\Delta]$ using any of the usual methods. This is a point at infinity for a parabola, as expected.

For the parameterization that you want, you need endpoints of conjugate diameters. Since the tangent to the conic at $\mathbf p_0$ is the $x$-axis, if we take $\mathbf p_0$ to be the endpoint of a diameter, its conjugate diameter is the horizontal line through $\mathbf c$. The coordinates of its endpoints are found by setting $y=w_0w_2/2(w_0w_2-w_1^2)$ in equation (3) and solving for $x$ to get $$x = {w_1^2+\Delta\pm2\sqrt{w_1^2\Delta} \over 2\Delta}.\tag4$$ By symmetry, if you start with $\mathbf p_2$ instead, the above expression gives the $y$-coordinates of the endpoints of the conjugate diameter. Letting $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ be the two points you’ve chosen, we then have the parameterization $$\tilde{\mathbf c}+(\tilde{\mathbf p}-\tilde{\mathbf c})\cos t + (\tilde{\mathbf q}-\tilde{\mathbf c})\sin t\tag5$$ for the ellipse. (Here, the tilde indicates the inhomogeneous Cartesian coordinates of the point.) The above also works for a hyperbola if you take the absolute value of $\Delta$ under the radical in (4), in which case the parameterization is $\tilde{\mathbf c}+(\tilde{\mathbf p}-\tilde{\mathbf c})\cosh t + (\tilde{\mathbf q}-\tilde{\mathbf c})\sinh t$.

Finally, you need to affinely map this to the original control points $P_0$, $P_1$ and $P_2$, which can be achieved via $(x,y)\mapsto P_1+(P_0-P_1)x+(P_2-P_1)y$. For the center of the conic this gives $\tilde{\mathbf c}'=P_1+{w_0w_2\over2\Delta}(P_0-2P_1+P_2)$ and I’ll leave working out the images of the two vectors to you.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I tried using $\tilde{\mathbf p}_\infty-\tilde{\mathbf c}$  in the parameterization as you did, but the direct computation got messy fast. I’ll have to try your approach to computing a conjugate diameter some time.

Answer (score 1):

The classic work on this subject is:

E. T. Y. Lee
The rational Bézier representation for conics.
In: Farin G, editor.
Geometric modeling: algorithms and new trends. SIAM; 1987. p. 3–20.

A more recent treatment is:

A. Cantóna, L. Fernández-Jambrina, E. Rosado María
Geometric characteristics of conics in Bézier form
Computer-Aided Design 43 (2011) 1413–1421

This latter paper also has references to several other works published between 1987 and 2011.

Comment: Thanks, however everything I've read seems to assume normalized weights $w_0 = w_2 = 1$, and so far I haven't figured out how to convert to that form if that's not what I start with.

Comment: The shape of the conic is determined by the ratio $w_0w_2/w_1^2$. You can modify the three weights however you like, and it won't change the shape of the curve as long as you don't change this ratio. So, you can replace the weights $w_0$, $w_1$, $w_2$ by new weights $1$, $w$, $1$, where $w$ is chosen to keep the magic ratio unchanged. Although these sorts of changes won't alter the shape of the curve, they will alter its parameterization. This is all covered in Gerald Farin's book, and elsewhere.