# quadratic bezier to parabola matrix equation

Tags: quadratics, bezier-curve, python

I'm trying to follow the matrix equation solution presented here: [Convert quadratic bezier curve to parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257576/convert-quadratic-bezier-curve-to-parabola) by @robjohn

I'm assuming his solution can be used for any quadratic coordinates.  My goal is to be able to pass in the coordinates defining a quadratic bezier curve, an `x` within the bounds of the curve, and get a `y` value out of it.

here's the python that I came up with:

```
a_x, a_y, b_x, b_y, c_x, c_y, x, y = symbols('a_x a_y b_x b_y c_x c_y x y')
u = Matrix([[b_y - c_y],[c_x - b_x],[b_x*c_y - b_y*c_x]])
v = Matrix([[c_y - a_y],[a_x - c_x],[c_x*a_y - c_y*a_x]])
w = Matrix([[a_y - b_y],[b_x - a_x],[a_x*b_y - c_y*a_x]])
expr = 2*(u*w.T + w*u.T) - v*v.T
lh = Matrix([[x,y,1]])
rh = Matrix([x,y,1])
```

My next steps were to run `collectExpr = collect(lh * expr * rh, y)` and then `collectExpr`, which gave me an extremely long expression following the format `Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0`, which I was then able to convert into the quadratic equation form.

Executing `collectExpr` at the python prompt will show the A, B, and C.  it's very long, so I'm leaving it out.

the problem I'm running into is when I solve for `y` and then compare that `y` against other solvers, the values aren't the same.  For example, I've got the following `juce::Path` drawing a quadratic:

```
juce::Path path;
path.startNewSubPath(0.0, 215.0);
path.quadraticTo(233.9999847412109375, 134.904998779296875, 400.0, 22.0);
```

there are member functions in the Path class to compute the intersection point with a line:

```
Line<float> line(28.984375, -5.0, 28.984375, 305.0);
```

When I check via the juce::Path member functions, I get an intersection point with a `y = 204.859955`, which I can visually confirm in my window as correct.

When I run those same values through the solver that computes the `y` for a Quadratic's control points and an `x` within those bounds, I get a different value. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c7556d1da7f7b0e

I've triple checked my C++ implementation against the resulting python from @robjohn's math via `collectExpr` output, and it's accurate.  But I can't figure out why I'm not getting the same y values as the `juce::Path::intersectsLine` functions to satisfy the equation.  Does anyone have any idea if that matrix solution is correct or usable?

the `juce::Path::intersectsLine()` looks similar to this:

```
bool CurveTableAudioProcessorEditor::intersectsPath(const Path &p, Line<float> line, Array<Point<float>> &possibleIntersections)
{
    //this is taken from Path::intersectsPath and modified 
    //to store intersections in the array
    PathFlatteningIterator i (p);

    Point<float> intersectionPoint;
    while (i.next())
    {
        if (line.intersects (Line<float> (i.x1, i.y1, i.x2, i.y2), intersectionPoint))
        {
            DBG( "  intersection: " << intersectionPoint.toString() );
            if( !possibleIntersections.addIfNotAlreadyThere( intersectionPoint ) )
            {
                DBG( "**** intersected point found twice! " << intersectionPoint.toString() << " for line: " << line.getStart().toString() << " " << line.getEnd().toString());

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but it might solve your problem.

As I understand it, you have a quadratic Bezier curve, and you want to find the $y$ value of a point on this curve corresponding to a given $x$ value.

Suppose the quadratic Bezier curve has control points $P_0$, $P_1$, $P_2$, and suppose $P_i = (x_i, y_i)$ for $i=0,1,2$. Then points $(x,y)$ lying on the curve satisfy the equations:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= (1-t)^2 x_0 + 2t(1-t)x_1 + t^2 x_2  \\
y(t) &= (1-t)^2 y_0 + 2t(1-t)y_1 + t^2 y_2 
\end{align}

Suppose we are given an $x$ value $x = \bar x$. Then we solve the equation 
$$
\bar x = (1-t)^2 x_0 + 2t(1-t)x_1 + t^2 x_2 
$$
to get the corresponding parameter value(s) $t=\bar t$. There might be zero, one, or two of these in the interval $[0,1]$.  Then we compute the corresponding $y$ value(s) $y = \bar y$ from
$$
\bar y = (1-\bar t)^2 x_0 + 2{\bar t}(1- {\bar t})x_1 + {\bar t}^2 x_2 
$$