# Showing that the image of a parabola under an invertible linear map is a parabola

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

A parabola $p$ is determined by a line $m$ and a point $P$ not on that line. Let $T$ be an invertible linear map on the real plane. I want to show that $T(p)$, the image of $p$ under this map, is also a parabola. There is a way to do it using equations, but it is very lengthy and I imagine that there are more elegant methods. In particular, I would like to know how to find the line and point that determine the parabola $T(p)$. Are they just the images of $m$ and $P$?

This is for homework so I appreciate that hints would be given and not full solutions.

Comment: The new focus and directix are not images of the old ones. For example, consider $y=x^2$. The linear map $\hat x=2x$, $\hat y=y$ keeps the focus and the directrix unchanged, however, the parabola changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT.

Let me add an even shorter argument, more suited to those who are not familiar with solid geometry. My original answer at the end.

The equation of any conic section can be written as
$$
\pmatrix{x&y&1}M\pmatrix{x\\y\\1}=0,
$$
where $M$ is a symmetric $3\times3$ matrix. 
[This conic section is a parabola if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) $\det M\ne0$ and $\det M_{33}=0$, where $M_{33}$ is the submatrix formed by the first two rows and columns of $M$.

Under a nonsingular linear transformation, whose inverse is represented by a $2\times2$ matrix $L$, the equation of the transformed conic section is then:

$$
\pmatrix{x&y&1}\hat{L}^TM\hat{L}\pmatrix{x\\y\\1}
=\pmatrix{x&y&1}M'\pmatrix{x\\y\\1}=0,
\quad\hbox{where}\quad
\hat{L}=\pmatrix{L & 0 \\ 0 & 1}.
$$

But $\det M'=\det(\hat{L}^TM\hat{L})=(\det L)^2\det M\ne0$ and
$\det M'_{33}=\det(L^TM_{33}L)=(\det L)^2\det M_{33}=0$, 
hence the conic section represented by the new equation is still a parabola.

By the way: this argument shows that also an ellipse and a hyperbola are transformed into an ellipse and a hyperbola respectively, under a nonsingular linear mapping.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER.

A parabola is always the intersection between a certain circular cone and plane $(x,y)$, that cone having a generatrix parallel to the plane.

You can extend your 2-D linear map to a non-singular 3-D linear map just adding that $z\to z$: under such a map, the cone transforms into another cone. As the mapping is non-singular, you can be certain that there still exists a generatrix of the transformed cone which is parallel to $(x,y)$ plane: it follows that the intersection between the transformed cone and the plane is still a parabola.

Note that the transformed cone will have, in general, an elliptic normal section. But the intersection between cone and plane is in any case a parabola, if a generatrix is parallel to the plane.

Comment: What do you mean by $M_{33}$? Is it the element of $M$ in the 3d row and 3d column?

Comment: @A.Γ. No, $M_{33}$ is the submatrix formed by the first two rows and columns of $M$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections .

Comment: [+1] Very complete answer now.

Comment: @Aretino Where did this notation come from? It seems conflicting with the standard matrix notations.

Comment: I vaguely remember that, when studying linear algebra, $a_{ij}$ was used for the $(i,j)$ element of matrix $A$, while $A_{ij}$ was the submatrix obtained from $A$ by deleting row $i$ and column $i$. I don't know if it is a widespread usage or not.

Comment: @Aretino Ah ok, it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a (maybe unexpected) explanation using the so-called quadratic Bezier representation of parabolas.

(classical) result: Any parabola can be given the following parametric representation:

$$\binom{x}{y}=(1-t)^2\binom{x_A}{y_A}+2t(1-t)\binom{x_B}{y_B}+t^2\binom{x_C}{y_C}.$$

([Convert segment of parabola to quadratic bezier curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335226))
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Symbolically:

$$\tag{1} M=(1-t)^2 A+2t(1-t)B+t^2 C.$$

where $A$ and $C$ are any distinct points of the parabola, and intermediate point $B$ is any point not aligned with $A$ and $B$ (in fact, it is the point of intersection of tangents in $A$ and $C$). Let us denote this parametric curve by ${\frak B}(A,B,C)$ : it is the Bezier curve defined by points $A,B,C$.

Now, applying any (invertible) linear transformation $L$ to (1) gives:

$$\tag{2} L(M)=(1-t)^2 L(A)+2t(1-t)L(B)+t^2 L(C),$$

(2) means that the image of Bezier curve ${\frak B}(A,B,C)$ by linear transformation $L$ is Bezier curve ${\frak B}(L(A),L(B),L(C))$, thus a parabola.

Remarks:

1) I leave as an exercise the fact that $L(A),L(B),L(C)$ aren't aligned (the fact that $L$ is invertible play here a role).

2) The sum of the weights in relationship (1) is always 1:

$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \ \ \ (1-t)^2 +2t(1-t)+t^2=1 $$

3) More generally, a linear transform preserves weighted sums (barycenters): the image of a weighted sum of vectors is the weighted sum of their images (with the same coefficients).

Answer (score 1):

You mean the focus $P$ and the directrix $m$? They determine parabola $p$ using locus of equidistant points. Unfortunately, in general, length ratios are not preserved by linear maps. However, in the Wikipedia article [Parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola) is mention of **dual parabola** which may help in your proof. There are other possible properties that you may want to use in the article as well.

Comment: I don't see the point to introduce the concept of dual parabola.

Comment: @JeanMarie It illustrates that parabolas are affine geometric objects. If you look at the figure with points $P_0,P_1,P_2$ the lines and points are mapped to corresponding points and lines by any invertible linear map, and thus the parablola is mapped to another parabola.

Comment: In fact, I should have had a look to the Wikipedia article you have mentionned before commenting too rapidly : there is a strong connection with the Bezier curves I use in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can assume without loss generality that the parabola $P$ is $\stackrel{\sim}{P}\,:y=x^2$, since any parabola can be taken to $\stackrel{\sim}{P}$ via a combination of rotation, translation, and scaling.

Hence, it suffices to consider the image of $(x,x^2)$ under invertible $T$.

---

It is hard to give a hint that does not solve the problem, but I encourage you to reflect on the 'without loss of generality' consideration above and think about how one can express $T$ in terms of simpler transformations for which you know the desired property holds, individually.

Comment: This feels a little circular.

Comment: @MichaelBiro Humm, how so?

Comment: They're trying to prove that (for instance) rotations take parabolas to parabolas, so they shouldn't assume that in the proof.

Comment: @MichaelBiro I think they're trying to prove that general invertible linear transformations take parabolas to parabolas. That this holds for some particular subset of these invertible linear transformations is obvious, especially ones that preserve distance, as per the locus definition of parabolas.

Comment: The catch is that,  aside from the orthogonal mappings you mentioned, there are shear mappings which are not orthogonal but still affine.

Comment: @Somos I'm not sure I understand your point.